# Applications stops working when uploaded on playstore

Tags: android, android-studio

I just uploaded my app on google play store and its crashing with following code

```
 Process: com.trifidresearch.trplsg, PID: 30335
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.trifidresearch.trplsg/com.trifidresearch.trplsg.intro.Country}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.am.v(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.am.b(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.app.x.setContentView(Unknown Source)
    at com.trifidresearch.trplsg.intro.Country.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:649)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.am.v(Unknown Source) 
    at android.support.v7.app.am.b(Unknown Source) 
    at android.support.v7.app.x.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
    at com.trifidresearch.trplsg.intro.Country.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.am.v(Unknown Source) 
    at android.support.v7.app.am.b(Unknown Source) 
    at android.support.v7.app.x.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
    at com.trifidresearch.trplsg.intro.Country.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.aj.a()' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v7.widget.at.setBackgroundDrawable(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:17244)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4337)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:80)
    at android.support.v7.widget.at.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.y(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.c(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:768) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.am.v(Unknown Source) 
    at android.support.v7.app.am.b(Unknown Source) 
    at android.support.v7.app.x.setContentView(Unknown Source) 
    at com.trifidresearch.trplsg.intro.Country.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629) 
    09-13 11:50:51.764 1585-2906/? E/ActivityManager: Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0
```

Its working fine on emulators and my phone when installed from `Android Studio` but as soon as I upload it on play store it unable to start.

**my code is**

```
package com.trifidresearch.trplsg.intro;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.trifidresearch.trplsg.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Country extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    EditText editsearch;
    String[] country;
    ArrayList<CountryNames> arraylist = new ArrayList<CountryNames>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .detectDiskReads()
                .detectDiskWrites()
                .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyLog()
                .build());

        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
                .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
                .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
                .penaltyLog()
                .detectAll()
                .penaltyDeath()
                .build());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.gradi));
    country = new String[] {
            "AFGHANISTAN(93)",
            "ALBANIA(355)",
            "ALGERIA(213)",
            "AMERICAN SAMOA(1684)",
            "ANDORRA(376)",
            "ANGOLA(244)",
            "ZIMBABWE(263)"
    };
    list = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++)
    {
        CountryNames wp = new CountryNames(country[i]);
        arraylist.add(wp);
    }
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    editsearch = findViewById(R.id.search);
    editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            adapter.filter(text);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
        }
    });
}
```

My gradle file id

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId 'com.trifidresearch.trplsg'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 20201
        versionName '2.2.1'
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86_64', 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
            //select ABIs to build APKs for
            universalApk true //generate an additional APK that contains all the ABIs
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            // signingConfig playStoreConfig //Add your own signing config
            pseudoLocalesEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
        debug {

        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}


ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 4, 'x86': 5, 'x86_64': 6]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride = android.defaultConfig.versionCode * 10000 + project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0)
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.14.2'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    implementation 'io.github.sac:SocketclusterClientJava:1.7.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please paste your xml code of where `Toolbar` is.

Comment: i am using default toolbar the title bar not added any in my xml

Comment: From where are you taking the .apk file?

Comment: @kgandroid didn't understood your question

Comment: @AmitKumarPawar Updating support library might help? The issue comes from `Toolbar`

Comment: After building the app for production you must be taking out the .apk file from some location.I want to know that location

Comment: @kgandroid  \app\release

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท i am already using latest version

Comment: Is the proguard set to true?

Comment: before uploading the .apk file to playstore,have you tested the apk in your device?

Comment: @kgandroid yes it is working fine on my phone as well as emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set Proguard `minifyEnabled` to `true`, then I'd assume that cause the crash. So, try adding these in the `/app/proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.** { *; }
```

This should help since you said you are already using the latest Support Library.

Comment: wait a min I am adding my gradel file

Comment: Like i said, `minifyEnabled` is `true` and it's in the release mode. So, adding those codes will help.

Comment: Do you have any proguard-rules file?

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: @AmitKumarPawar `/app/proguard-rules.pro` every project has since it is enabled by progaurd.

Comment: You shouldn't add that proguard rules in your project. Because there is no point using `minifyEnabled` true when you're telling it to not obsfucate all the support library.

Comment: you may b right sir , but i was unable to do any thing and this is working for now with this proguard changes...... and the thing is it is running in alpha testing with same code but suddenly this problem occured... any ways  thank you  @ʍѳђઽ૯ท

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with this drawable

> R.drawable.gradi

As it is mentioned in your error log last line

> Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 0x0

Please check once after removing it.